# SharePoint on Amazon Web Services

Tags: configuration, domain, amazon-ec2

I'm installing SP2010 Enterprise on AWS EC2.  I have downloaded SharePoint and installed it.  My problem is getting through the Configuration Wizard.

I'm creating a new server farm.

I'm having problem with "Specify Database Access Account"  I think this is because I'm not sure what my exact "DOMAIN\User_Name".

Can someone help me get through this?

Answer (score 1):

I planned a farm on AWS a little while ago. Unfortunately customer didn't move forward with it, but we were going to include  a server for active directory. AWS doesn't provide an AD to work with.